# How can I return data from a .json file with Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to store data in a .json file, and I want to also be able to fetch this data by using a discord bot using discord.py

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use json, but instead use a database like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)

Still want to use json? Use the [json module](https://realpython.com/python-json/) that is built in to python.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json

data = { 
"foo": "bar"
}

#write json to file
file = open('json.json', "w")
json.dump(data, file);

#read json from file
file = open('json.json', 'r')
jstring = json.load(file)

#output: bar
print(jstring['foo'])
```

A simple google trick would of done it.

Comment: what about closing the file?